# jQuery fade css background image and color

Tags: jquery

here is the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Zg55k/

How can I change css background image and color smoothly with fade effect. When press background-image should fadeOut and background-color fadeIn in same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make 2 layers. The layer that you want to fade in must have a higher z-index (or places below the other layer in the code) and have opacity: 0;
Then gradually change the opacity to 1, for exmaple with jQuery animate.

HTML:

```
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box2">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box1 {
    background-image: url(http://www.webdesign.org/img_articles/14881/site-background-pattern-07.jpg);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.box2 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.box1').click(function(){
    $('.box2').animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
});
```

See jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/9D32K/

You also may do

```
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

But then you should position the boxes absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried classing the element and using CSS3 transitions?

`transition: background 0.5s linear;`

When you change the background, either with toggleClass or with your code,     `$('#box1').css('background-color','black');`  it will fade as defined by the class.